# Can i store the places suggested by places api in our scenario?

Tags: google-maps, google-api

we have app hosted on google app engine for java. In this app we ask for address information of blood donors who register with us.

For the address part we want to use google places api where blood donor may start typing the city names and we may pull them from the places api. Then based on the selection we may store the address values in the google data store.

Is there a restriction of such type of data usage from google maps policies ?

Comment: Can you clarify and explicitly state which information returned by the Places API you intend on caching?  Are you talking about using the Autocomplete API?

Comment: well we want to store city, state , country and zip code information to our db returned by autocomplete api when user selects one of the returned suggested values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your clarification the answer is no.  You're looking to permanently store information on your DB for each user's selection.  Per the [Google Maps API Terms of Service](http://goo.gl/4WZaM), section 10.1.3b:

> (b) No Pre-Fetching, Caching, or Storage of Content. You must not
>   pre-fetch, cache, or store any Content, except that you may store: (i)
>   limited amounts of Content for the purpose of improving the
>   performance of your Maps API Implementation if you do so temporarily,
>   securely, and in a manner that does not permit use of the Content
>   outside of the Service; and (ii) any content identifier or key that
>   the Maps APIs Documentation specifically permits you to store. For
>   example, you must not use the Content to create an independent
>   database of "places" or other local listings information.

If you are going to ***temporarily*** use this information, then the answer is maybe, although you should ask your legal counsel to review the terms of service to ensure that your proposed approach does not violate the terms.